# rendering blob content as code instead of text

Tags: grails, groovy, blob, render

I have the following code saved in the oracle database as a blob field , basically html and embedded groovy code with an sql which return some values

```
<%
        import groovy.sql.Sql

        def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB","root", "root", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
%>

<html>
        <head>
                <title>Database Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <table align="center" border="1">
                        <tr>
                                <td>Id</td>
                                <td>LastName</td>
                                <td>FirstName</td>
                        </tr>
                        <% sql.eachRow("select profile_id profileId, last_name lastName, first_name firstName from profile") {profile->  %>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>${profile.profileId}</td>
                                        <td>${profile.lastName}</td>
                                        <td>${profile.firstName}</td>
                                </tr>
                        <% } %>
                </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

Now I am having the above blob value in the variable thistemplate.contents, which I am trying to render on renderthistemplate.gsp as shown below:

```
def renderString= g.render(template:"myController/renderthistemplate",model:[rendertemplate:thistemplate.contents])
```

Now in the gsp I just do `${rendertemplate}` to print the whole blob. 
Expected is that it should execute the whole blob as code and render the output.
But it is actually printing the contents of the blob as a plain string, neither the HTML nor the groovy code is executed in the target GSP.
How can I have the target GSP to actually render the blob contents as code and not as string/text
Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. For security reasons, the special symbols in the string must be escaped or hackers could enter the following name: `me'; delete from user;` which would delete all data in the user table as soon as you display the name on the web page (simplified example but you get the idea).

You could [render the blob as text](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) using `contentType:"text/html"` but that wouldn't run the code in the `<% %>` blocks.

The solution is to create your own dynamic template. You need two things for this:

1. Create a new field in your controller:

   ```
   GroovyPagesTemplateEngine groovyPagesTemplateEngine
   ```
2. Use this code to render the blob:

   ```
   groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(blobAsString, “somepage.gsp”).make(model).writeTo(out)
   ```

code sample from: [Grails – Rendering a Template from a String](http://disgruntleddevs.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/grails-rendering-a-template-from-a-string/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the reference, we will be trying this out!

Comment: Just had a question, will this call make a new template gsp every time.. depending on the blobasString

Comment: Sure; it's not a full GSP but the code which builds a template from the `.gsp` file. How else should it compile&run the Groovy code from the blob? If this is a performance problem, I suggest to create the template once when you start your app and then call `make()` on this shared template.